# is there a way to order methods that run before the XAML starts? (MvvM)

Tags: c#, methods, maui, maui-shell

In an `Mvvm` application, I have a page that has two methods that run in the ViewModel before the Xaml runs.  They run in the wrong order, and I'm wondering if there's a way to tell it which method to run first.

The method that runs *second* is the implementation of the `IConvertible` [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1164621/shell-navigation-and-passing-parameter-values), used to pass an object from a previous page. I would like it to run first.

The method that runs *first* is `Appearing()`, which is the [MVVM answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1186365/net-maui-viewmodel-alternative-to-onappearing) to the `OnAppearing` method.  I would like it to run second.

```
    // this method runs first, I would like it to run second
    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task Appearing()
    {
        // no access to VideoObj because this method runs before ApplyQueryAttributes
        string x = VideoObj.ThumbnailFilename;
    }

    // this method runs second, I would like it to run first
    public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
    {
        Package = query["Package"] as VideoPackage;
        VideoObj = Package.video;
    }
```

Is there a way in C# or Maui to order this kind of thing?

Comment: Why don’t you just put the code in Appearing in the other method?

Comment: How do you set the BindingContext of this page?  ApplyQueryAttributes method should run first and then comes Appearing command. I don't know why you get the opposite result. Could you please share more code to help us reproduce?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you trigger a method after both have been fired, so it is order agnostic? e.g.

```cs
    bool Appeared { get; set; } = false;

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task Appearing()
    {
        Appeared = true;
        if (Appeared && VideoObj !== null) HandleThumbnail();
    }

    public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
    {
        Package = query["Package"] as VideoPackage;
        VideoObj = Package.video;
        if (Appeared && VideoObj !== null) HandleThumbnail();
    }

    private void HandleThumbnail()
    {
        string x = VideoObj.ThumbnailFilename;
    }
```

Comment: If I did that, then both methods would happen after the Xaml had run.  I need both methods to run pre-Xaml.  With that said, this is a good technique.